# Which port to open by a WCF service?

Tags: .net, wcf, port, portforwarding

I created a WCF service, and its working if I type this url:
http://192.169.1.103/MyService/SomeService.svc

That IP is from my intranet.

It also work if I change that IP to localhost.

Unfortunately, I guess I need to port foward, because if I change that IP to my internet IP, it doesn't work. =(.

I have a router and a modem-router. (So thats 2 routers =x). But what port do I have to open? I dont understand this part.

**Edit:** I have a few knownledge in port foward. But It's the main problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard http port is 80, if you use https then it would be 443.

Comment: I have a router and a modem-router. The 192.169.1.1 is the IP of my router. How can I find the ip of my modem-router to open ports in there too please? Thanks

Comment: @Seva: You have to open port 80 on your external IP - it is visible e.g. here http://whatismyipaddress.com/. You have to configure your router to forward external traffic on port 80 to 192.168.1.103:80.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are serving it up over port 80 on your local computer. You can port forward to that, but it probably isn't a great idea for lots of reasons.

Comment: aren't the routers supposed to already have the port 80 open?

Comment: The router just decides where to send incoming traffic. It doesn't serve anything up by default. And you would still need to tell it where to forward that traffic to. Otherwise it would have no clue which computer on the network to route the port:80 traffic to.

Comment: I have a router and a modem-router. The 192.169.1.1 is the IP of my router. How can I find the ip of my modem-router to open ports in there too please? Thanks